# Add an boolean attribute to a text field?

Tags: 7, entities

I need to add a boolean attribute in the form of a check-box to a ordinary multivalued text field attached to a node. In this case, the text field will be used to list arguments for functions, which can either be required or not-required. So, in a node-edit form, I envision it to look something like the screen below. What's the best way to go about this?

[image: text field with attribute]

Edit: adding links to suggested options, and also some that I found while checking these out:

1. field collection - https://drupal.org/project/field_collection
2. field collection table - https://drupal.org/project/field_collection_table
3. double field - https://drupal.org/project/double_field
4. tablefield - https://drupal.org/project/tablefield
5. multifield - https://drupal.org/project/multifield (dev)

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own field type and widget form. A good example can be either filefield or imagefield.

Or try [Field collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module.

So you can create a new type of field in field_collection UI.

Here are tutorials: https://drupal.org/node/1353926

Answer (score 2):

[Field Collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module is what you looking for. **OR**, if you don't want to use field collection module for any reason, you want to make your own field type. You can follow this tutorial from Phase2 and suit it to your needs:

http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/compound-fields-in-drupal-7/